# Add a footer to UITableView at the bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am doing a slide menu using a `UITableView` and I have 2 options on the menu and I want to put a button at the bottom like in this image:

[image]

I try to do that add a `tableFooterView` like that.

```
UIView *footerView  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 500, 320, 70)];
footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView;
```

However, the view appears just after the second cell, but I want it at the bottom.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you have more than 2 cells?

Comment: no I only have 2 cells

Comment: Well, that's why it's not at the bottom of the window -- it's supposed to be at the bottom of the table view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know that every `UITableViewCell` has its height and footer is part of a `UITableView` and will appear at the bottom of a `UITableView`. If you want to make your `UITableView` look like what that image shows, you should make sure that your cells are high enough to make sure that your `UITableView` are high enough so that footer will appear at the bottom of `UITableView`

My suggestion is to add extra "empty" cell(I mean a cell with no content but has a height).

Answer (score 9):

No you shouldn't add any empty cells, that's just hacky. If you really need the button to be at the bottom, you should use layoutSubviews to control the frame of the tableView and the footerView.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
   [super layoutSubviews];
   self.tableView.frame = // top 80% of the screen
   self.footerView.frame = // bottom 20% of the screen
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a Container View with View Controller from storyboard. You can use autoresizing to set the buttons on right place.

Comment: You can do directly placing container view at bottom of table view. It will create a View and you can create separate view controller to initialise buttons.